# My script for setting combattext give exception

Tags: c#, exception, unity-game-engine, null

my TextManager script is like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TextManager : MonoBehaviour {

private static TextManager instance;
public RectTransform canvasTransform;
public GameObject textPrefab;
public float speed;
public Vector3 direction;


void Start() {
    speed = 1f;
    direction = (new Vector3(0,1,0));
}

public static TextManager Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<TextManager>();
        }
        return instance;
    }
       }



   public void CreateText(Vector3 position)
   {
    GameObject sct  =  (GameObject)Instantiate(textPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
    sct.transform.SetParent(canvasTransform);
    sct.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(0.08f, 0.08f, 0.08f);
    sct.GetComponent<CombatText>().Initialize(speed, direction);
}
}
```

CombatText is like this

```
using System.Collections;

public class CombatText : MonoBehaviour {

private float speed;
private Vector3 direction;
private float fadeTime;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    float translation = speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(direction * translation);

}

public void Initialize(float speed, Vector3 direction) {

    this.speed = speed;
    this.direction = direction;


}
}
```

this is how i call it TextManager.Instance.CreateText(transform.position);
i have no idea why it gives that NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TextManager.CreateText (Vector3 position) (at Assets/TextManager/TextManager.cs:37)
PlayerControl.Update () (at Assets/Player/PlayerControl.cs:35)

any tips?

Comment: please format your code more carefully, hit edit and use the "code format"

Comment: Will do. sorry for that. have to learn to make propebly formated code.

Comment: Double check in inspector if `textPrefab` has already attached `CombatText` component. I bet it has not.

Answer (score 1):

In line 37 of `TextManager` class is: `sct.GetComponent<CombatText>().Initialize(speed, direction);`

The only thing that can be null in this line is `GetComponent<CombatText>()`

So to fix this. Attach in inpsector the `CombatText` component to `textPrefab` or add it in runtime: `sct.AddComponent<CombatText>().Initialize(speed, direction);`.

Comment: Jerry has spotted the problem, nice one!